# Activity is stuck on process dialog and wont go to the next page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

So i recently updated my code with the latest admob SDK and dependencies.
it is supposed to show an interstitial ad before going to the next page.
upon running it the StartActivity is stuck on process dialog and wont go to the next page.
here is the code

```
                //Start Here
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

                InterstitialAd.load(StartActivity.this,StartActivity.this.getString(R.string.main_inter), adRequest,
                        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                                // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                                // an ad is loaded.
                                pd.dismiss();

                                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                                mInterstitialAd.show(StartActivity.this);
                                mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdClicked() {
                                        // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                        // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                        // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.

                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                                        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        StartActivity.this.finish();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                        // Called when ad fails to show.
                                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdImpression() {
                                        // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                        // Called when ad is shown.
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                                // Handle the error
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                            }
                        });
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Dismiss the dialog in `onAdLoaded`. 2. You are not using `mInterstitialAd.show(activity)` on the loaded Interstitial. 3. There is no `startActivity` but a `finish` in `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` which will finish the current activity.

Comment: I have implemented all the above but now the app crashes immediately i click the button.

Comment: Can you trying using `mInterstitialAd.show(StartActivity.this);` after you've set the `setFullScreenContentCallback`? And also post the crash stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You are not dismissing your progress dialog upon `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent`

```java
@Override
  public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
  // Called when ad is dismissed.
  // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
  pd.dismiss()
  mInterstitialAd = null;
  StartActivity.this.finish();
}
```

**Always remember to handle dialog states, or it can cause window leaks.**

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity before `finish()` is called

```
@Override                               
    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
        // Called when ad is dismissed.
        // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
        pd.dismiss()
        mInterstitialAd = null;
        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        StartActivity.this.finish();
        

}
```

Comment: Confirm if i'm missing sth in the edited code. unfortunately its still stuck on loading processDialog

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss the dialog if the interstitial fails to load or show.

```
private void openNextPage(ProgressDialog pd){
    pd.dismiss();
    mInterstitialAd = null;
    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    StartActivity.this.finish();
}
```

```
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(StartActivity.this,
                StartActivity.this.getString(R.string.main_inter),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        // Don't dismiss dialog here as we are going to show interstitials now

                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                openNextPage(pd);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                // Called when ad fails to show.
                                openNextPage(pd);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is shown.
                            }
                        });

                        mInterstitialAd.show(StartActivity.this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        openNextPage(pd);
                    }
                });
```